# Robot_state_publisher dies on ARM-based Turtlebot

Tags: robot-state-publisher, ros-indigo, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Whenever I run `roslanch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch` I get the following error:

```
[robot_state_publisher-2] process has died [pid 1597, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher __name:=robot_state_publisher __log:=/home/odroid/.ros/log/02472614-0afe-11e5-884e-c22209f25fe8/robot_state_publisher-2.log].
log file: /home/odroid/.ros/log/02472614-0afe-11e5-884e-c22209f25fe8/robot_state_publisher-2*.log
```

The log file is empty, however. If I run `rosrun robot_state_publisher robot_state_publisher` I get a segmentation fault. When I compile and run `robot_state_publisher` using gdb, here's the seg fault info:

```
Starting program: /home/odroid/catkin_ws/devel/lib/robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb660bc74 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpcre.so.3
```

I'd imagine this is because I'm running everything on an Odroid U3 with Ubuntu 14.04 and [ROS Indigo Ubuntu ARM](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM). Anyone else have this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210607/robot_state_publisher-dies-on-arm-based-turtlebot/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2015-06-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vishu2287](https://answers.ros.org/users/23634/vishu2287/) on 2015-08-20**:
Hi. Im using Jetson TK1  and facing the same problem. Did you get out of it? please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Robot state publisher has died error code -7](http://answers.ros.org/question/210272/robot-state-publisher-has-died-error-code-7/) and [turtlebot apt-get update has generated an error on minimal.launch](http://answers.ros.org/question/209686/turtlebot-apt-get-update-has-generated-an-error-on-minimallaunch/) are probably related.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3